# Can't select some mysql data and store it to a variable in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

All of the other variables that make this work are tested and working correctly so I'm obviously doing this wrong.

I have a bash script that first selects some mysql data and stores into a new variable.

Then it goes on to connect again and update the database.

```
title=$(mysql -u $user -p$pass -h $host dbname | SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=$8);

mysql --host=$host --user=$user --password=$pass dbname <<EOF
UPDATE wp_my_music_lib SET title = "$title" WHERE track_id=${4}${6};
EOF
```

The `title` entry is always blank which says to me that the initial SELECT isn't working properly. It should also be noted that the data expected from the select result has white space and special chars in it ie :

```
Some Artist (10/10/13)
```

I thought quoting the var `"$title"` would fix any potential problems with gobbling but that isn't the issue here as I've tried selecting a single numerical object from a different column and that doesn't work either.

If I hard code the title var it works as expected.

1) Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

2) Is it possible to perform all of the above with one db connection instead as that would make more sense?

Comment: You probably have a line `SELECT: command not found` that shows up on your terminal, hopefully giving you a hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: So code wise, the above *should* be working?

Comment: Well, working with a syntax error (I'm not sure whether I'd call this _working_)… and `title` would indeed be empty in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql | SELECT` pipes the output of `mysql` to a command called `SELECT`, which is сertainly not what you want.

To execute a query via `mysql` and capture the output you can use this syntax:

```
title=$(mysql -B dbname <<< "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=$8")
```

You could also execute the `SELECT` in a subquery to avoid multiple calls to `mysql`:

```
mysql --host=$host --user=$user --password=$pass dbname <<EOF
UPDATE wp_my_music_lib SET title = (
 SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=$8)
WHERE track_id=${4}${6}
EOF
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! I got that SELECT code (with the piping) from other posts here on SO asking about the same kind of thing.